# How can I define the location of a custom editor template when using MVC areas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

It is my understanding that the location is:

```
~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ViewModelName
```

However I have many Views folders using areas. Can I define the file to use with some parameter of the call to the

```
@Html.EditorFor( ...
```

Answer (score 8):

Those are default lookup paths which RazorViewEngine will search for editor template, in this order:

```
"~/Areas/{area}/Views/{controller}/EditorTemplates/{templateName}.cshtml",
"~/Areas/{area}/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/{templateName}.cshtml",
"~/Views/{controller}/EditorTemplates/{templateName}.cshtml",
"~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/{templateName}.cshtml",
```

If not specified, `templateName` value defaults to object type (in your case 'ViewModelName'). If template with this name is not found by MVC will fall back to resolve rendering using known build-in templates (int, string, collection, object, etc).

You can specify template name to override defaults:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyDate, "_MyTemplate")
```

You can also specify relative paths:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyDate, "../_MyTemplate")
```

You *cannot* specify full paths in any form (ex:`"~/Views/Custom/EditorTemplates/ViewModelName"`) and you *should never* specify extension in template name (ex: `'_MyTemplate.cshtml'`, or `'_MyTemplate.vbhtml'`)!

Answer (score -1):

You could pass the location of the template as second argument.

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo, "~/Views/Custom/EditorTemplates/ViewModelName.cshtml")
```

This being said I would avoid doing this and stick to the conventions. This means that if you want to use some editor template from outside the area where it is defined then you probably didn't define this template at the right place and should move it in the Shared folder.

Comment: Doesn't it always default to the shared folder? I want to keep it very local if possible.

Comment: @RichardM, yes, it defaults to the Shared folder. But from what I understood from your question you are trying to use some custom location for your editor templates. If you don't follow the conventions you need to specify the path to the template.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't specify full paths for editor templates.